# In Rust, how can I pass fast always-empty and single-entry HashMaps to a third-party API?

Tags: performance, optimization, rust, hash, hashmap

I am using a third-party API (the GCloud SDK from https://lib.rs/crates/gcloud-sdk) that uses HashMaps in its types to pass key/value pairs to the GCloud webservice and back. A field that contains such a hash map is specified like this:

```
pub labels: ::std::collections::HashMap<
    ::prost::alloc::string::String,
    ::prost::alloc::string::String,
>,
```

which is just a long way to say HashMap<String, String>. Many of these fields will contain empty hash maps or single-entry hash maps. Since the default hasher is considered "slow", I'd like to be able to optimize these maps if they become a bottleneck. My intention here, for now, is really just the *ability* to optimize if it becomes a problem, not prematurely optimize before I know *if* it is a problem.

The performance concern consists of two things:

- that generation of a new RandomState is expensive (AFAIK if even reads from /dev/urandom), affecting even empty hash maps
- that hashing a single key is somewhat expensive, less than the above but still total overkill for a single-element map since few of the advantages of hash maps apply to single-element maps

My initial idea was therefore to replace the hashing algorithm by a much simpler one, and for empty maps even by a no-op. However, I don't understand how this is supposed to work. I wrote a no-op implementation, wrapped by a function like this:

```
pub fn create_nop_hash_map<K, V>() -> HashMap<K, V, NopBuildHasher> {...}
```

I'm leaving out the implementation of NopBuildHasher since it is trivial and not related to the problem I'm having.

This gives me an error:

```
labels: create_nop_hash_map(),
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `HashMap<String, String>`, found `HashMap<_, _, NopBuildHasher>`
```

The "labels" field is defined in the third-party library, so changing its type isn't possible for me. I could obviously ask the author to change that field, but what *should* it look like? That library cannot know in advance which maps I'm going to leave empty. It seems to me that the only thing I could realistically ask the author is to define a new type parameter for every map-typed field, and since these parameters would cascade through the enclosing structs, the whole library would be cluttered with type parameters for the hash algorithms. This does not seem realistic to me.

The alternative approach I wanted to try is to leave the default Siphash-1-3 algorithm and just use hardcoded initial values, but I can't do this either because the RandomState fields are private and there is no constructor to specify them directly.

The last thing I could think of is to ask the author of the library to not use hash maps at all for these fields, but e.g. list-of-key-value-pairs, but it seems to me that I'm totally on the wrong track here because using a custom hashing algorithm is, I think, a common use case that many people have done before.

What would be the idiomatic way to pass hash maps with custom hashing algorithms to third-party APIs? Alternatively, what is the idiomatic way to optimize empty or single-element hash maps?

Answer (score 3):

In the current versions of Rust, creating a new `RandomState` instance is very cheap. Only the first `RandomState` instance a thread creates is initialized with random keys. All further instances [reuse the cached keys](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/31356) and [simply increment one of them by one](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/36481). This should alleviate any concerns about empty hash maps. The performance problem was fixed in Rust 1.10, released in July 2016, and the potential DOS problem in Rust 1.14, released in December 2016.

The main cost for a hash map with a single key is most likely the allocator, not the hasher. If the hash map contains a key, it needs to allocate memory, which is most likely far more expensive than computing a single hash. Optimizing the hasher is unlikely to help in any significant way for this use case.